# DRF ERROR: Django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: django, djangorestframework, serialización

Estoy realizando una API que es un clon de instagram.

Ya tengo toda la parte de users lista, solamente me falta la de post.

El problema que tengo es que al querer crear un post me sale el siguiente error:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint

Cual puede ser la causa?

Dejo la vista, el model y el serializer.

VIEWS.PY
(es una clase que hereda de varios mixins y de GenericViewSet)

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
def create_post(self, request):
    """Create post."""
    serializer = PostCreateSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    post = serializer.save()
    data = PostModelSerializer(post).data
    return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

MODELS.PY

```
class Post(InstagramModel):
    """Post model.

    THE FAVS SYSTEM IS THE NEXT STEP.
    """

    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User',related_name='posts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='posts/files/')
    text = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
    'is active post',
    default=True,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        """Return post user."""
        return self.user.username
```

SERIALIZERS.PY

```
class PostModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
"""Post model serializer."""

class Meta:
    """Meta class."""

    model = Post
    fields = '__all__'
    read_only_fields = (
        'user',
        'file',
        'text'
    )


class PostCreateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
"""Post create serializer.

Handle create data validation.
"""

file = serializers.FileField()
text = serializers.CharField(max_length=500, allow_blank=True)

def create(self, data):
    """Handle post creation."""
    post = Post.objects.create(**data)
    return post
```

Comment: Como dice el error, al crear un post estas violando la restricción de que el id no sea `null`. Entonces verifica que al crear un post estes instanciando al usuario que esta creando el post para que el el campo de id no quede vacío en la tabla `Post`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que se te presenta en forma de excepción, es un problema de integridad por parte de la base de datos. En la definición de tu modelo `Post`, tienes definida una llave foranea obligatoria hacia el modelo `User`, esto ocasiona que la base de datos defina un constraint que force a cada `Post` a tener un usuario relacionado. En tu caso estas intentando crear un `Post` sin un usuario asignado, es por eso que al momento de intentar guardar la instancia, la base de datos arroja un error que se ve transformado en un `IntegrityError` en Django.

**Soluciones**

Para solucionar el problema debes asignar un usuario al campo `usuario` del post y eso se puede traducir en que debes pasar un objeto `User` al serializer, de manera que pueda ser utilizado como parte de la información proporcionada al momento de crear el post, algo similar a:

`post = Post.objects.create(user=user, **data)`

Generalmente en este tipo de casos el usuario autor del post es el mismo usuario que realizó la petición, es decir, `request.user`. Para pasar este usuario al método `create` existen principalmente dos formas.

1. Pasarlo como argumento al momento de llamar el método `save` del serializer, que resultaria en:

```py
...
post = serializer.save(user=request.user)
...
```

Todos los argumentos extras pasados en el método `save` son proporcionados en el diccionario `validated_data`, en tu caso es el argumento `data` que estas recibiendo en el método `create` del serializer. Debido a que estas desempaquetado todos los valores con `Post.objects.create(**data)`, no es necesario modificar algo más.

> **Nota.** Esta view esta tomando como premisa que toda petición entrante corresponde a un usuario autenticado. Idealmente la view debería estar protegida para que solo los usuarios autenticados puedan ejecutarla.

2. Una segunda forma es a través del serializer field `CurrentUserDefault`. Al definir un campo de un serializer como `CurrentUserDefault`, este va tomar el valor del usuario que realizó la petición y no va poder ser sobrescrito por el usuario.

Un requisito necesario para utilizar este último método es que el serializer debe recibir el objeto `request` como parte de su contexto, es decir, al momento de instanciar el serializer debes pasar un diccionario en el argumento `context` que tenga una entrada con el objeto `request`.

```py
serializer = SerializerClass(..., context={'request': request})
```

Esto es automáticamente pasado en el caso de que se este utilizando un `Viewset` para generar los endpoints, pero en tu caso es necesario realizarlo a mano.